# Can the [grub] and [grub2] tags be turned into synonyms?

Tags: discussion, synonym-request

The [GRUB](https://www.gnu.org/software/grub/) project has a non-linear history. The original GRUB codebase was replaced by the [PUPA](http://www.nongnu.org/pupa/) project in preparation for the release of version 2.0 (first existing as v1.98 and v1.99). This new codebase has colloquially been referred to as **GRUB2**, but that has never been its official name. The original codebase is now known as "**GRUB Legacy**".

These days, the vast majority of questions on both the [grub](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/grub) and the [grub2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/grub2) tag relate to **GRUB** rather than **GRUB Legacy**. The "correct" thing would be to delete the [grub2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/grub2) tag and move all such questions to [grub](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/grub) (heck, there's only 21 of them - I could edit them myself), but realistically, people would keep creating it.

There does remain a case for a grub-legacy tag.

I would put up a synonym suggestion, but "Version specific synonyms can only be created by moderators.".

Comment: I would guess that a lot of the questions these tags get aren't really suitable for Stack Overflow, and should instead be asked on [su] or [unix.se]?

Comment: @TZHX: Most definitely, but that does not really relate to this request. Some of them are on-topic.

Answer (score 1):

[The Ubuntu manual](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2) refers to it as GRUB 2, and so does [the GNU manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/grub.html). While you may have a point, I think it's better that we follow the principle of least surprise and use the most common naming.

Comment: The Ubuntu manual uses incorrect terminology and admits as much: "In this guide, GRUB 2 is version 1.98 or later. GRUB legacy (version 0.97) will be referred to as GRUB.".
As for the GNU manual - you are referring to a document titled "GNU GRUB Manual 2.00" containing four non-purged instances of "grub2", 21 of "grub 2" and 708 of "grub".