# Can the [grub] and [grub2] tags be renamed?

Tags: discussion, tags, retag-request

The GRUB tags on Stackoverflow have actively misleading names (there is no GRUB2 project), but my [previous request](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/317056/can-the-grub-and-grub2-tags-be-turned-into-synonyms) to have [grub](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/grub) and [grub2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/grub2) synonymized went mostly unnoticed.

The current state is as follows:

[grub](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/grub) has a tag wiki that describes the project that has been called **GRUB Legacy** [since 2002](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_GRUB#Development).

[grub2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/grub2) has a tag wiki that (briefly) describes the project that is known as **GRUB**, this too for 14 years.

So if we can't have them as synonyms, can we instead rename the tags to match what their tag wikis are describing? [grub](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/grub) -> [grub-legacy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/grub-legacy) and [grub2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/grub2) -> [grub](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/grub)? If so, could it be coupled with a synonym tag of [grub2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/grub2) created for the [grub](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/grub) tag unless there is a mechanism to blacklist a specific tag from being created with new questions?

Yes, this will mean some questions on [grub-legacy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/grub-legacy) end up incorrect. I would be happy to manually re-tag all on-topic questions after a rename.

There are many improvements that could be made to both tag wikis, but doing so while the tags themselves are incorrectly named does not feel like it would help reduce confusion.

Comment: It's annoying that bounties are not possible on Meta, but please do not recreate a question because it went unanswered. Make a small edit so it's bumped to the top again.

Comment: Well, it wasn't a recreation - it was proposing an alternative solution to the one that was not reacted to. The mechanism of the synonym proposed here is completely different from the creation of a synonym between the currently existing grub and grub2 tags.

Comment: Incorrect closure on my part then, sorry. Voting to reopen.

Comment: Is there actually enough of a difference between "old GRUB" and "new GRUB" to need both tags? (Particularly considering that probably >90% of questions in the combined tags belong on SuperUser.)

Comment: @duskwulf: current GRUB was originally referred to as GRUB2 because it was a replacement (new codebase and design) rather than an iterative change. Arguably, there is no place for grub legacy on stackoverflow, since it is a dead project. Not sure the posters of those 90% read tag wikis and guidance, but the current state of the tags makes cleaning those up a bit pointless (not to mention it would be highly unclear what to do),

Answer (score 3):

Most people I know have been saying *grub two* for the last 14 years, and they would say *old grub* if they happened to talk about the old times. In this situation, `grub` and `grub2` should be synonyms and refer to the current versions, while questions about historic software should be retagged as `legacy-grub`. I fully support this proposal of @unixsmurf’s, while I am not sure that the proposal of simply merging `grub` and `grub2` would be wise.